# C string concatenation not working

Tags: c, string

I'm absolutely new to C language, so please bear with me. The purpose of below program is to take a string input from user, split it on "-" character, then concatenate the first character of all individual parts. For example:

```
Rivest-Shamir-Adleman
```

should return:

```
RSA
```

The code works perfectly upto the splitting part. The `input` variable stores the user input, `result` is a char pointer to store the actual concatenated result, and I use the `strtok()` function to actually split the string. But the following concatenation part isn't working:

```
*result++ = token[0];
```

The `result` variable should print `RSA` in above example, but its just printing `-`. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *input;
    char *result;
    input = malloc(256); //don't read more than 255 chars.
    result = malloc(50); //don't read more than 50 chars.
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("You entered %s\n", input);
    printf("Length is: %u\n", strlen(input));
    char *token = strtok(input,"-");
    while(token) {
        printf("%c\n", token[0]);
        *result++ = token[0];
        token= strtok(NULL, "-");
    }
    *result++ = '\0';
    printf("result: %s\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("result: %s\n",result);` : `result` isn't top of string.

Comment: When you do `result++` what happens with the pointer in `result`? Where does it point after that? So when you want to print `result`, where does it *actually* point?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ideally, it should point to the next character in the memory stack - that's what I gather from the example where I took that from, but apparently its not (though I've done `malloc`).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY If I understand correctly, the `result` need to point back to the first memory location in order for the value to get printed?

Comment: A C string is a sequence of characters terminated by a zero, so far you're correct. But the "string" itself is usually a pointer to *its first character*. That's how string functions work, they have a pointer and then continue along the memory until it hits the terminator. When you attempt to print `result` then it is pointing to *beyond* the terminator.

Comment: @PrahladYeri yes,  E.g fix `char *rs;` .. `rs = result = malloc(50);` ... `printf("result: %s\n", rs); free(rs);free(input);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine. Its just that you preserve the start of the result string.  `result = temp;`Output the same in answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *input;
    char *result, *temp;
    input = malloc(256); //don't read more than 255 chars.
    temp = malloc(50); //don't read more than 50 chars.
    result = temp;
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("You entered %s\n", input);
    printf("Length is: %u\n", strlen(input));
    char *token = strtok(input,"-");
    while(token) {
        printf("%c\n", token[0]);
        *temp++ = token[0];
        token= strtok(NULL, "-");
    }
    *temp++ = '\0';
    printf("result: %s\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("Length is: %u\n", strlen(input));` -> `printf("Length is: %zu\n", strlen(input));` or `printf("Length is: %u\n", (unsigned)strlen(input));`

Comment: @chqrlie `%zu` seems to work only on linux for some reasons, not on windows (at least with gcc compiler).

Comment: @PrahladYeri: More precisely, it is a library issue: `%zu` is not supported by the Microsoft Runtime C Library.  `%zu` has been part of Standard C for 18 years, it is supported on Linux and MacOS and many other systems. On legacy systems, you may have to use the work around: `printf("Length is: %u\n", (unsigned)strlen(input));` `%u` is inappropriate in Windows 64-bit because `size_t` is larger than `unsigned`.